# vim how to fold an html tag

Tags: vim, folding

I see a few posts saying I should use `zfat` to fold html tags.  So i tried it but did not get the results I expected.  For example, I had this in my document

```
<div id="begin">
   <p>hello world</p>
      </div>
```

I moved my cursor in vim to the first line of `<div id="begin">`.  Then I pressed escape to make sure I'm in command mode.  Then I pressed the keys `z`, `f`, `a` and `t`.  But nothing happened.  I even tried typing `z`, `f`, `a` and `{`, which normally folds blocks of PHP code, but it has no effect on the html.

Can some one tell me the exact steps to fold the html div tags?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`zf` indeed is the command to create a manual fold. For that to work, you need to have

```
:setlocal foldmethod=manual
```

(There will be an `E350` otherwise.) The `at` is a *text object* for *a tag*. You can check what it comprises by applying it to visual mode instead: `vat`.

Note that manual folding is tedious; I'd recommend to use the *syntax folding* that comes with the built-in HTML syntax plugin. Just put

```
:setlocal foldmethod=syntax
```

in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/html.vim` to enable it.

Also note that so far (as of Vim 7.4.1830), the default HTML syntax script only folds a multi-line tag itself, **not the text between the opening and closing tag**. To achieve that, you need a syntax extension, see [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2333/970).

Comment: +1 for the suggestion of using `vat` to see what will be affected.

Comment: weird, my vim is the latest version 7.4 and yet there doesn't seem to have a built-in html syntax plugin? there is no fold support for html files even when foldmethod is set to syntax

Comment: I don't have this file on my windows machine. Using `gvim`. Any help?

Comment: @ThomasSebastian: The scripts in the _after_ directory are meant for your customizations. It's normal that it doesn't exist yet. Just create it :-) (But note that on Windows, `~/.vim` usually is `C:\Users\yourname\vimfiles`.)

Comment: @Ingo Karkat Thank you. That helps.

Comment: It doesn't work with html syntax fold method, and my vim is the latest version 7.4. @zanona, Have you solved this problem?

Comment: @soarinblue: The built-in folding might not be what you'd expect, see [here](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2333/970) for an extension that you probably want.

Comment: Thank you @Ingo. I read your link, which has solved my problem.